# Read Announcements, Questions and Assignments with in course using Google Classroom API?

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client, google-classroom

How can I get full access to specific course including Announcements, Questions and Assignments using Google classroom API?

Are APIs to access assignments out yet ??

Answer (score 0):

As of Feb 2016 it's not possible to get access to announcements, questions and assignments via the Classroom API.